# Change the position of UIToolBar iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, uitoolbar

I am creating an UIToolBar via Interface Builder.
I set it as an IBOutlet.

Within the `viewDidLoad` of my `viewController` I am trying to set the frame.

What I want to achieve is modify the position of it so it can be animated.

But nothing happens.

Is there a different way to do that?

Thanks

```
myOwnToolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 55);
    [self.view addSubview:myOwnToolBar];
```

Comment: I could make it worked adding the toolBar programatically. However if I do it via IB I can't move it. I tried to add the .frame code in the viewDidLoad, init... but nothing

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to create a `UIToolBar` programmatically, you can't just set a frame without allocating and initializing the toolBar. Try this:

```
myOwnToolBar = [[UIToolBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:myOwnToolBar];
```

When you create an IBOutlet, an alloc/init call is implied. You just need to keep in mind that this is not true for objects created in code.

Comment: When I created via Interface builder I was trying to access self.myOwnToolBar.fram =... but it wasn't working. I was doing that in the viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

Little hack with **swift 3**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { 
        self.navigationController?.toolbar?.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: -216)
    }
}
```

**Objective-c** example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.navigationController.toolbar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -216);
    }];
}
```

Set your variables or constants for **animation duration**, **x-offset** or **y-offset**